# What does exit code 250477278 of a Delphi application mean?

Tags: delphi, error-handling, delphi-2006

We have a customer who has a problem, that our Delphi application does not seem to start. But we cannot reproduce it here.

The program however is starting, but immediately and silently exits with error code 250477278.  Does anybody know, what this error code means (and where it is defined)?

**Edit:**
Nowhere in our code we have calls like `Halt(ErrorNumber)`, so it seems, this error code is coming directly from Delphi?

Comment: As a general piece of advice, it's always a good idea to convert decimal error codes into hex. Because programmers usually write them as hex, and when you need to type them into a search engine, you have vastly more chance of succeeding if you use hex. At the very least search for both the decimal and hex representations.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The hex representation would have led me to the right explanation. sry

Comment: No need to say sorry. It was just a piece of hopefully helpful advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That decimal value is, in hex, `0EEDFADE`. That is the SEH code for a native Delphi exception. So, it would seem that your program is throwing a native Delphi exception that is not being handled. And it is doing so before the Delphi RTL exception handling mechanism is in place to deal with it.

It's impossible for us to say what in your code is causing this to happen, since we don't have the code. What you need to do is some debugging. You first of all need to identify the exception and work out where and why it is being raised. I would start by adding madExcept (or similar) to the project and collect some more information about this exception.

Comment: And _before the Delphi RTL exception handling mechanism is in place_ normally means before `Application.Run`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be useful - both for the person who set up the topic and for the next people who will get here. I myself had a very similar problem, the customer reported exactly this exception - 0EEDFADE, we could not replicate it at debuging. Finally, I put the compiler at the client's place and it turned out that Delphi reported this error when trying to read / write non-existent files - the client's folder structure was simply damaged. Of course, I understand that there may be other problems that can result in this error message, but that's what I was able to reproduce. Sorry for newbie answer. :)